# How to add a HTML element in WordPress ADMIN edit post window?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I'm a newbie to WordPress plugin development. I'm creating a plugin that will fetch a image from some APIs such to flickr and store its values such as its URL in the database. And that particular image will be displayed to the end user along with the content.

Now, I'm trying to create a feature in my plugin which lets the user to see the preview of the image in the admin post window once it is published (in the edit post window).

But I couldn't able to identify any hooks for making that preview in the admin edit post window.

Is there any hooks to add a HTML image tag in the admin edit post window? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One image per post? Then you can set it as featured image. Would it be ok?

Comment: No, I have to set it apart from the featured image..

Comment: Then you can create a [custom filed](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields) and a [metabox](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/) for desired post edit screen with functonality to preview the image (you have also place this filed in your output-template) or you just append the image tag to post_content.